# How to execute custom fish scripts in custom path folder

Tags: fish

I'm having trouble executing a fish shell script I created. I added it to a custom path I added using `fish_add_path`. The folder appears just fine in `$fish_user_paths` and `$PATH`, and i've CHMOD +x the file, but when I type the name of the file, (which is pickc ath the moment), it can't find the command. How do I add fish scripts to the path and execute them like any other cli command (e.g. pickc)?

The content of the script is:

```
#!usr/bin/fish

colorpicker --short --one-shot --preview | sed -z 's/\n//g' | xclip -selection c
pkill picom
picom -b
```

I can execute the script just fine with the `fish -c pickc` command, but I can't execute with `./pickc`, which gives me the error

`Failed to execute process './pickc'. Reason: The file './pickc' does not exist or could not be executed.`

I have doubly confirmed that the path in the `$PATH` and `$fish_user_variable` variable does lead to the folder containing the script.

Edit: I noticed that my paths were all really messed up somehow. The below answer does fix the issue of not being able to execute it, so thanks

Comment: What is the filename

Comment: the filename is pickc. The first line has the shebang #!/usr/bin/fish, which is the output of which fish.

Comment: Running `fish pickc` on the directory works. But I can't do `./pickc`. The error is "Failed to execute process './pickc'. Reason:
The file './pickc' does not exist or could not be executed."

Comment: Your shebang line is incorrect. It should be `#!/usr/bin/fish` (notice the leading slash in the path). That assumes, of course, you installed fish as */usr/bin/fish* rather than, say, */usr/local/bin/fish*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mistyped your shebang. Switch

```
#!usr/bin/fish
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
```

or whatever path `which fish` shows.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it work with `./pickc` when i'm already in the folder with your answer, however I still can't execute the script as a global command.

Comment: Sounds like the directory is not in your $PATH then. You can use `fish_add_path /path/to/directory` to add it.